# How to implement protocol buffers (de)serialization on a Java client talking to a .NET server utilizing protobuf-net v2?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

If I understand it correctly, the Java end needs the respective .proto file. However, it is unclear to me how to generate one from the RuntimeTypeModel instance (protobuf-net v2) used on the server side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At current, it simply hasn't been re-written; there is a v1 version of `GetProto()`, however it won't apply to v2 as it needs to be heavily refactored to work from `RuntimeTypeModel`. It is simply a case of finding time to put the code together.

If the model is moderately sized, I can probably help hook it together manually.

Note also that protobuf-net offers some features that *will not* map very nicely into .proto, since they have no definition *at all* in core .proto (these are usually clearly documented as extension), such as:

- reference tracking
- inheritance
- dynamic types

Additionally, some of the BCL core types do not have direct .proto counterparts, including:

- Guid
- DateTime
- TimeSpan

these *can be interpreted*, but require a little more shuffling

Comment: Hi Marc. The model is indeed moderately sized, but then again, how do you define moderate?

Comment: @mark - well, roughly how many types and members are we talking?

Comment: (also, see the edit re some things that might not map cleanly)

Comment: 8 types, 27 properties total. I am sorry, but I did not grok your reservations regarding the extension features. Would it not be true to say, that using the extensions result in a valid .proto spec, which corresponds to a different data model than the original one? Like extra objects to implement the reference tracking. These are valid objects and valid proto spec, only the data objects would require an additional processing to unfold the shared references, strip dynamic type markers, etc... Am I correct?

Comment: Guid, DateTime and Timespan can be read as plain strings just fine, can't they?

Comment: @mark no; if you want them encoded as strings, introduce a shim property that *is* a string of the desired format; i.e. `private string WhenString { get { return When.ToString(format, ..); } set { When = DateTime.Parse(...); } }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3230/discussion-between-mark-and-marc-gravell)