# Making Fiddler understand (i.e. decode) an HTTP request/response encoded with protocol buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers, fiddler, protobuf-net

**Given:**

1. Windows
2. Client-Server communication over HTTP with protocol buffers
3. Agent-Server communication over HTTP with protocol buffers (a different .proto spec)
4. Both .proto files are available

**Needed:** the ability to examine the decoded HTTP traffic per request/response.

Fiddler seems an ideal tool for this and in fact I am using it constantly. However and quite understandable, it cannot decode the requests/responses encoded with protocol buffers. On the other hand I know that:

1. Fiddler can be extended
2. Given the respective .proto files, the protocol buffers output can be easily decoded.

My question is whether anyone else has encountered with the same issue and whether there is a way to resolve it.

Of course, I prefer fast and easy solutions over long and hard ones (like writing a Fiddler extension from scratch), but in the absense of the former I guess I would settle for the latter as well.

To all the good samaritans out there - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wireshark may be your friend here, since there is an existing plugin: [protobuf-wireshark](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-wireshark/)

Comment: Oh, excellent news. I have wireshark installed as well, though for debugging HTTP traffic I find Fiddler much more convenient. Now all that is left is generate these proto files (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329553/how-to-implement-protocol-buffers-deserialization-on-a-java-client-talking-to-a/7329981#7329981) :-).